# <.Created>: can't evaluate field Created in type *formatter.imageContext

Tags: docker, docker-image

I was trying to get the information of docker image based on "creation date" of the image.

When I ran the below command

```
docker image list --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Repository}}\t{{.Created}}"
```

I was getting below errors

Template parsing error: template: :1:26: executing "" at <.Created>: can't evaluate field Created in type *formatter.imageContext

Comment: I found the solution after looking formatter code [link]https://github.com/BrianBland/docker/blob/master/api/client/formatter/formatter.go           solution is - docker image list --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Repository}}\t{{.CreatedAt}}"

Comment: Please put answers even if they're your own as answers, not comments, and accept them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `CreatedAt` instead of `Created`, so like this:

```
docker image list --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Repository}}\t{{.CreatedAt}}"
```